# creating popup on click for tiny rich text editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to implement the Tiny rich text editor into my code. Here is the component called TextEditor.js for the editor:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

class App extends React.Component {
  handleEditorChange = (content, editor) => {
    console.log('Content was updated:', content);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
        init={{
          height: 500,
          menubar: false,
          plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
          ],
          toolbar:
            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
            alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
            bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
        }}
        onEditorChange={this.handleEditorChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the file (DogPaddle.js) where I want to implement it in:

```
import React from 'react'

const DogPaddle = () => {
   return(
 <a onClick={} href="javascript:void(0)">
 </a>
   )
}

export default DogPaddle
```

BTW this is how DogPaddle is called in Dog.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
     user: {},
     user_data: []
   }
   render() {
    
        return (
        <div>
            <div>
                    <DogPaddle
                    >
                    </DogPaddle>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
  }
}
```

The desired outcome is to be able to have a popup with the rich text editor upon clicking the anchor tag. I also want to be able to transmit the data from the rich text editor back to DogPaddle.js. Can anyone help me out? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use onChange

```
onChange={(value, editor) => {
                editor
                  .getBody()
                  .getElementsByTagName('a')
                  .item(0)
                  ?.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    console.log('123213');
                  });
              }}
```